# Javascript variables not adding, only concatenating as strings

Tags: javascript, string, math

I have some simple code that should add two numbers and it seems to keep adding them, i.e. if I have a variable that is initialized as 0 , I add 100 once, and then I add 200, it seems to add it as follows 0 + 100 + 100 + 200, returning 400 NOT 300.  How can I get this to add correctly?

```
function calcScores(amount) {
    amount = parseInt(amount,10);
    for(var key in teamSelection) {
        if (teamSelection[key]['Selected']) {
            score = parseInt(teamSelection[key]['Score'],10);
            var total = +score + +amount;
            teamSelection[key]['Score'] = total;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So now are they being concatenated, or is it just that the result of the addition incorrect, although numerical?

Comment: You add `amount` on each iteration of the loop. What is the value of `amount`?  If there are 5 scores, the sum you'll get will be the sum of the scores plus `amount * 5`

Comment: `amount` and `score` are already numbers so remove the extra plus sign in `+score + +amount` to change it to this `score + amount`.  Not sure if that is the problem, but it isn't necessary and the two `++`  signs in a row could be at least a confusion.

Comment: The code - as provided seems to work with a basic dataset ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0rfq5m6/)).  You must have something else going on elsewhere.

Comment: @dc5 I think you are right, for I tried it on the JSFiddle as well, and it appears to work fine.  It probably has something to do with using .bind('click', function(){//somestuff}), wherein the some stuff, it's calling another function, that has a bind/click in it.  Any ideas how to track that down, i.e. what might be getting looped up?  Thanks.  You can look at this to get an idea of what all is going on:  http://jsfiddle.net/55FY8/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = +score + +amount;
```

This line is confusing to me. If you want to add score and amount to total, use

```
var total += score + amount;
```

Comment: It may look funny, but it's there (out of superstition, because the values are already numbers here) to force a numeric `+` operation. I agree that it's not necessary but it won't hurt anything.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reproduce the problem in a smaller scale, without other factors. Most of the time, by reducing the problematic snippet to something trivial, the issue becomes evident.

You should also include in your questions the actual output vs the expected output.

As it is now, all I can do to help you is point out two suspicious parts in your code:

1. `parseInt` can return `NaN` or `undefined`. You don't handle these cases.
2. `total = +score + +amount` has a few extra addition symbols, that shouldn't make any difference, but hey, this is javascript. Perhaps `total += score + amount`.

If you want more help, you'll have to narrow down the problem to something specific: _this code produces this output instead of this other output".

Comment: The notion that JavaScript is randomly broken is really not true. The superfluous unary `+` operators won't hurt anything.