# Javascript repeating when doing simple addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

Had trouble like this, of things not adding correctly, in a previous question, [Javascript variables not adding, only concatenating as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295541/javascript-variables-not-adding-only-concatenating-as-strings?noredirect=1#comment39424429_25295541), but the straight javascript worked fine.  I have now built all the code in JSFiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/trout0525/L2hhof79/7/

Finally the calcScores routine repeats, like the version I currently have on the webpage I'm working on.  Here is the JavaScript that I think is the culprit, mainly with the binds that I'm using, but I'm not sure why:

JavaScript:

```
    var selectionName= [
        "100pointsCol1","200pointsCol1","300pointsCol1","400pointsCol1","500pointsCol1",
        "200pointsCol1","200pointsCol2","300pointsCol2","400pointsCol2","500pointsCol2"
    ];

var teamSelection = {};
teamSelection['1'] = {};
teamSelection['2'] = {};
teamSelection['3'] = {};
teamSelection['4'] = {};
teamSelection['5'] = {};

teamSelection['1']['Selected'] = false;
teamSelection['2']['Selected'] = true;
teamSelection['3']['Selected'] = false;
teamSelection['4']['Selected'] = false;
teamSelection['5']['Selected'] = false;

teamSelection['1']['Score'] = 0;
teamSelection['2']['Score'] = 0;
teamSelection['3']['Score'] = 0;
teamSelection['4']['Score'] = 0;
teamSelection['5']['Score'] = 0;



window.onload = function() {
    $(function(){
        for (var i=0; i < selectionName.length; i++) {
            selection = selectionName[i];
            $("#" + selection).bind("click", {sName: selection}, makeSelection);
        }
    });
}

function makeSelection(event) {
    selection = event.data.sName;

    $("#" + selection).unbind("click");
    openQuestion(selection);
}



function startGame() {
    showGameboard();
}

function showGameboard() {
    $("#scoreboard").css("z-index", 100);
    $("#gameboard").css("z-index", 100);
    $("#startboard").css("z-index", 1);
}

function openQuestion(selection) {
    $("#scoreboard").css("z-index", 1);
    $("#gameBoard").css("z-index",1);
    $("#questionWindow").css("z-index",100);

    amount = selection.substr(0, selection.length-10); 

   $("#questionWindow").bind("click", function(){
        openAnswer(amount);
    });
}

function openAnswer(amount){

    $("#questionWindow").unbind("click");

    $("#questionWindow").css("z-index",1);
    $("#answerWindow").css("z-index",100);

    $("#answerWindow").bind("click", function(){
        calcScores(amount)
        showGameboard();
    });
}

function calcScores(amount) {
    $("#answerWindow").css("z-index",1);

    amount = parseInt(amount,10);

    for(var key in teamSelection) {

        var total = 0;

        if (teamSelection[key]['Selected']) {
            score = parseInt(teamSelection[key]['Score'],10);
            alert("score: " + score + "\n" +
                  "amount: " + amount + "\n" +
                  "total: " + total);
            var total = +score + +amount;
            alert("score: " + score + "\n" +
                  "amount: " + amount + "\n" +
                  "total: " + total);
            teamSelection[key]['Score'] = total;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

So, why is it repeating the calculation?

Comment: Seems redundant to have a document ready nested inside of a window onload.  Does the same behavior happen if you remove the `window.onload` from around the document ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2hhof79/22/

### The Problem

**This is occurring because you are binding your answer window's click event handler multiple times.** That event handler then calls calcScores().

See below:

```
function openAnswer(amount){
    $("#questionWindow").unbind("click");

    $("#questionWindow").css("z-index",1);
    $("#answerWindow").css("z-index",100);

    $("#answerWindow").bind("click", function(){
        calcScores(amount)
        showGameboard();
    });
}
```

So, every time the openAnswer() function runs, *another* event handler is bound to answerWindow's click event. In other words, every time you make a selection, calcScores() will be called an additional time.

### Potential Fix

The quickest fix would be to change your bind() function calls to one() function calls:

```
$("#questionWindow").one("click", function() { //...
```

and

```
$("#answerWindow").one("click", function() { //...
```

This will only allow the event handler to be bound for one call.

### Another Bug

There's also a typo in your declaration for the **selectionName** variable. The typo results in binding two event handlers to the **200pointsCol1** selection. You should see why. I fixed this in my jsFiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This appears to have done the trick.  I thought there was something going on funny with the 'click' binds, and I thought unbind would resolve any issue that had to do with it going twice, but apparently it did not.  I did not know about the 'one' function.  I'm pretty sure that takes care of my problem.  The JSFiddle code was not my actual code, but it was close, so the one little typo of having two entries is problem not anything significant.

Answer (score -1):

Because you're using two onload callbacks..

remove this

window.onload = function() {
   }